# Instance of RoleManager/IServiceProvider in .NET 7 Blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, iserviceprovider

In .NET Core 3.1, we were able to create roles on startup like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
  CreateRoles(serviceProvider).Wait;
}
private async Task CreateRoles(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            var RoleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        .... //do your thing with the RoleManager instance.

}
```

However, in .NET 7 (and in 6 as well) the Configure method is not there from where we can get an instance of IServiceProvider.

How do I do that in .NET 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to Create a scope then access the `RoleManager<>` from there.

`Program.cs`

```
...

using var scope = app.Services.CreateScope();
using var roleManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();

...
app.Run();
```